# Node JS Jasmine Testing multiple types with jasmine.any()

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

I'm using Jasmine ([v2.2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html)) for testing, and I'm trying to spy on a method which is expected to be called with specific data for the first argument, and unknown type for the second.

I'm familiar with [spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Spies) and the `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` syntax on spies, and joined with `jasmine.any()` it may look something like this:

```
expect(my.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('startMenu', jasmine.any(String));
```

But I'm unable to find a method to deal with several types.
What I'm looking for is a method to perform the same action, where the second parameter is any type, and just as well, when the second param is one of some types, like:

```
// Any type is okay:
expect(my.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('startMenu', jasmine.any());

// String or number only:
expect(my.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('startMenu', jasmine.any(String OR Number));
```

Needless to mention, the previous examples are not working code, they are just what I'm looking for the correct syntax for.

On another note, I have found `jasmine.anything()` which will handle *almost* anything, but fails with `undefined`.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to do this by just using `jasmine.any` but you could achieve something similar with a custom matcher:

```
toBeStringOrNumber : function () {
  return {
    compare : function (actual, expected) {
      return {
        pass : (typeof actual == 'string' || typeof actual == 'number'),
        message : actual + ' is not a string or a number'
      };
    }
  };
}
```

And then call it on the actual parameter:

```
expect(my.spy).calls.argsFor(0)[1].toBeStringOrNumber();
```